# PostgreSQL synchronous stored procedure execution calls from Django Backend

Tags: python, django, postgresql, stored-procedures, synchronous

We have 5 PostgreSQL stored procedures and we need them to be chronologically executed in order.
We have them listed in one stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE main(input_file_path varchar)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
begin as $$
CALL get_input_file(input_file_path);
CALL gla_first_step();
CALL glab_first_step();
CALL jet_first_step();
CALL completeness();
end;
$$
```

We need `gla_first_step` procedure to be called after `get_input_file` procedure is done etc

We have tried using `PERFORM` as was suggested by GPT but that brought the following error:

```
ERROR:  get_input_file(character varying) is a procedure
LINE 1: SELECT get_input_file(input_file_path)
               ^
HINT:  To call a procedure, use CALL.
```

We have tried calling them separately from our backend with a loop of SELECT 1 to simulate a wait
but that also did not work.

```
            cur.execute('CALL get_input_file(%s)', [path])
            result = None
            while result is None:
                cur.execute("SELECT 1")
                result = cur.fetchone()

            cur.execute('CALL CALL gla_first_step()')
            result = None
            while result is None:
                cur.execute("SELECT 1")
                result = cur.fetchone()

            cur.execute('CALL glab_first_step()')
            result = None
            while result is None:
                cur.execute("SELECT 1")
                result = cur.fetchone()

            cur.execute('CALL jet_first_step()')
            result = None
            while result is None:
                cur.execute("SELECT 1")
                result = cur.fetchone()

            cur.execute('CALL completeness()')
            result = None
            while result is None:
                cur.execute("SELECT 1")
                result = cur.fetchone()
```

Comment: `Begin` is actually part of the code block and defines the start of a transaction. `As $$` informs Postgres that dollar quoted string follows, basically that is what code is - just a string. However it is not actually part of the code block. In short `begin as $$` is backwards abs should be `as $$ begin`.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried and it's still asynchronous. Any other suggestions?